# Angular distance in Keras as metric

Tags: keras, deep-learning, metrics

I am using Keras to train my model and want to use angular distance between my predictions and hypothesis as my metric. The closest metric I have found so far is cosine proximity, not angular distance though.

The problem I have with cosine proximity (or cosine distance) is that the cosine for small numbers are very similar.

Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity), it is possible to calculate the angular distance using cosine proximity:

[image: formula]

So I am wondering if using a custom metric based on cosine proximity is a good idea and if so how is that implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think I have the answer to my own question. What I did is I first calculated the cosine proximity by simply using the Keras's source code. Then I calculated the Arc Cosine of the previous result:

```
def angular_distance(y_true, y_pred):
     y_true = K.l2_normalize(y_true, axis=-1)
     y_pred = K.l2_normalize(y_pred, axis=-1)
     cosine = K.sum(y_true * y_pred, axis=-1)
     return 2*tf.math.acos(cosine)/np.pi
```

Then I passed the new function as a custom metric to model's compilation script:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(0.001),
            metrics=[angular_distance])
```